# Error at install JBoss RHQ

Tags: jboss, rhq

When I'm trying to execute the "rhq-encode-value" from the RHQ Server (4.1.3) I get the following error:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal SERVER\bin\rhq-server.properties

Wich in english means:

> Error: Can't find or load the main class SERVER\bin\rhq-server.properties

This happen when I'll try to install the server using the "rhqctl install" command after I set up the jboss.bind.adress direction too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running rhq-encode-value or rhqctl --install?

The only place I can think of where a value needs to be encoded is the password of the database user, and this would be done before you run the rhqctl command. The password of the default 'rhqadmin' user is prompted for during installation and encoded.

Make sure you have set JAVA_HOME correctly and that you have java on the PATH. JAVA_HOME can be set in rhq-server-env.sh as value RHQ_SERVER_JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And this appears when I'm running the rhq-encode-value. But when I use rhqctl --install it happen to. I tought that the problem was because I was using the wrong JAVA_HOME because I modified those values and it worked. So for me this is the answer.